# Why does changing it so my content script runs for http sites instead of all urls make the content script show up in Developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

I'm learning about Chrome extensions and making some hello world apps. I'm working on Content scripts here.

Firstly, my app is very simple, it is just a manifest that loads a content script.

This is the manifest

```
{
  "name": "turn all th into TH",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,

 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScriptFirstApp.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the contentscript is just one line

> alert('hello');

Now i run this, the alert box shows up every time a page is loaded.

However, the strange thing is, although the code is running, i cannot find the ContentScript in the Developer tools.

It's only when I make a slight adjustment to my manifest, changing the matches parameter so that instead of allowing , it only matches with http files as below that I can see the content script in the developer tools.

```
{
  "name": "turn all th into TH",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,

 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentScriptFirstApp.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Just curious why this is. In both cases, the code is running and showing the alert box, but why is it only when the content script pages has the "matches" parameter set as http pages only that it starts to show up in the developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is just coincidence and a glitch I often see when first loading an extension.

When I use your `"<all_urls>"` manifest, I see the `contentScriptFirstApp.js` just fine in the *Sources* tab of the dev tools.  I can switch to the content script context just fine.

But it seems that sometimes when *first* installing an extension from disk, that the *first* tab's dev tools don't always see it.  I [and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059078/use-the-tampermonkey-api-from-the-chrome-console/14059557#comment-19431566) have seen this problem but I haven't figured out a reliable way to duplicate the issue on demand.

Whatever the cause, closing that tab and opening a new one always fixes it (so far).  So probably there was enough going in between when you changed the manifest that the extension *coincidentally* made an appearance in dev tools.  Like I said, the manifest works and the extension shows up for me, irregardless of the `matches` settings.

Comment: ur right, even the http thing doesn't work anymore. It looks like it's not the changes but just chrome developer tools being buggy. Closing the first tab and opening a new one doesn't seem to fix it either :(

Comment: Oh dear.  Might be time to restart chrome and any tasks it has running.  Might be (silent) errors in the code?

Comment: I closed down another one of the test extensions I was doing and it seems to be working now. Although I'm sure once again it's just coincidence - the extension is just another simple one. It's good to be aware of this issue i guess.

Comment: Good luck.  If you figure out a reliable way to trigger this glitch, please let us know.  That would be a first step to getting Google to fix it.