# How does GM_getTab(cb) work?

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

There does not appear to be any information on how these functions work. I presume these are Tampermonkey exclusive functions?
It looks like they are designed to allow communication between currently running Tampermonkey scripts; An alternative to continually polling GM_Value storage for changes. Which is a really interesting idea.

But I have no idea how to use them; What values they take in, and what sort of object you get back?
How do you use these three functions, and am I right in their purpose?

> **GM_getTab(cb)**
>   Get a object that is persistent as long as this tab is open.
>
> **GM_saveTab(tab)**
>   Save the tab object to reopen it after a page unload.
>
> **GM_getTabs(cb)**
>   Get all tab objects in an array to communicate with other scrips
>   instances.
>
> (http://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=74)

Comment: I think the way to avoid continually polling is actually `GM_addValueChangeListener` like so: `GM_addValueChangeListener("foobar", function(key, oldval, fval){console.info(key + " previous: "+oldval +" value:" + fval);});` but these 3 functions help you if you want to send simple key:values as notifiers (like [tabId]:[tab_version]++ or newTabOnline:[tabId]) and then rely on them for the shared state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd never attempted to use them, but looking at the code these appear to be the ability to store/get whatever you would like from each tab and also get everything stored in this fashion by all tabs.

On two chrome consoles, I have run the following:

```
var this_tab_data, all_tabs, n;

GM_getTab(function (o) {
    this_tab_data = o;
    n = this_tab_data.rand = Math.random();
    GM_saveTab(this_tab_data);
    console.info(this_tab_data);

    GM_getTabs(function (db) {
        all_tabs = db;
        console.info(n);
        for (var i in all_tabs) {
            if (all_tabs[i].rand === n) console.info("I bet I am the tab named: " + i);
            else console.info("Other tab: " + i + " has value: " + all_tabs[i].rand);
        }
    });
});
```

Result (in tab 2):

```
Object {rand: 0.9303610376082361}
VM779:11 0.9303610376082361
VM779:14 Other tab: 366 has value: 0.417106909211725
VM779:13 I bet I am the tab named: 371
```

I added access in the chrome console using this user script, (based on the instructions on the indicated `@match` page):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059078/use-the-tampermonkey-api-from-the-chrome-console
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.GM_getTab = GM_getTab;
unsafeWindow.GM_saveTab = GM_saveTab;
unsafeWindow.GM_getTabs = GM_getTabs;
```

As a side note, I see that this data remains accessible with GM_getTabs() after I close the tabs that set it. I'm not sure I would count on that, but I probably would minimize what I left behind.

Answer (score 0):

lossleader's answer is complete. In short, `GM_getTab()` passes a *copy* of the "tab object" to `cb` (It's now `callback` in the latest doc of Tampermonkey), `GM_saveTab()` saves the `tab` object into the *real* "tab object", and `GM_getTabs()` passes all the tabs running the current script to `cb`, as a hash.

So the procedure of identifying a browser tab should be:

```
// Get it
GM_getTab(function(tabObj) {
  // Modify it
  tabObj.id = genID();
  // And store it
  GM_saveTab(tabObj);
})
```

Or with `Promise`:

```
new Promise(r => GM_getTab(r)).then(function(tabObj) {
  tabObj.id = genID();
  GM_saveTab(TabObj);
})
```

(In addition) what the `GM_getTab()` & `GM_getTabs()` passes to the callback is like:

```
getTab():  {…}
​            + id: "166471588778160035"
            + <prototype>: Object { … }

getTabs():  {…}
​             + 9: Object { id: "166471588778160035" }
​             + 25: Object { id: "599671588779026059" }
​             + 26: Object { id: "154331588779031451" }
​             + 31: Object { id: "622271588779033558" }
​             + 33: Object { id: "542881588779039564" }
             + 36: Object { id: "112571588779028937" }
​             + 38: Object { id: "549981588779038186" }
​             + <prototype>: Object { … }
```

(Update) The "tab object" being passed to the `callback` are isolated between scripts, so scriptA gets a "tab object" different from scriptB

```
setTabExpr1.user.js:26:15 {…}
​                           + a: 1234567
                           + <prototype>: Object { … }
​
setTabExpr2.user.js:26:15 {…}
​                           + b: 7654321
​                           + <prototype>: Object { … }
```